# react-native-video with dynamic url

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm using fetch to call API for video URL. I have trouble with **react-native-video**.the video is not showing.

```
<Video
  repeat
  resizeMode='cover'
  source={{uri:`${this.state.base_url}${item.video}`}} 
  style = {styles.backgroundVideo} 
/>
```

I'm getting a blank screen. In documentation, they mention like below code.

```
source={require('../assets/video/turntable.mp4')}
```

How can I render dynamic URL like mentioned above?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using this compoenet and it's working properly, fetching from API.

```
<Video
  source={{
    uri: this.state.waitingVideoURL,
  }}
  resizeMode="cover"
  style={styles.backgroundVideo}
  repeat
  onLoad={this.stopLoading}
/>
```

In your code, why you having two variables in the source; What's  `item.video` ?

```
source={{uri:`${this.state.base_url}${item.video}`}}
```